# Why do my slider thumbnails select the wrong image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a slider on the page that switches images. Everything almost works, the images switch, but when I click on the preview, the main image does not display the selected one, but the adjacent one. What could be the problem?

```js
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function() {
  let currentSelection = $(this);

  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(currentSelection).addClass('selected');
  let index = $(currentSelection).index();
  $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select').prevAll('.main-image').hide();
  $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select').prevAll('.main-image').eq(index).show();
  $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select').prevAll('.custom-carousel__title').find('span').html($(currentSelection).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

```css
.custom-carousel {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-image>img {
  width: 50px;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item>img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.img-to-select {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item.selected {
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image" style="display: block">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-a">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" data-title="image-a">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" data-title="image-a">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-b">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" data-title="image-b">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" data-title="image-b">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-c">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" data-title="image-c">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" data-title="image-c">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-d">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" data-title="image-d">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" data-title="image-d">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" alt="" data-title="image-a">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" alt="" data-title="image-b">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" alt="" data-title="image-c">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" alt="" data-title="image-d">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image" style="display: block">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-a">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" data-title="image-a">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" data-title="image-a">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-b">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" data-title="image-b">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" data-title="image-b">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-c">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" data-title="image-c">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" data-title="image-c">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-d">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" data-title="image-d">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" data-title="image-d">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" alt="" data-title="image-a">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" alt="" data-title="image-b">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" alt="" data-title="image-c">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" alt="" data-title="image-d">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated your main image selector to simplify. The `prevAll()` function gets previous siblings, which is needlessly specific. We just want all elements inside the parent container.

```js
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function() {
  let currentSelection = $(this);

  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(currentSelection).addClass('selected');
  let index = $(currentSelection).index();

  $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select').prevAll('.main-image').hide();
  $(currentSelection).closest('.custom-carousel').find('.main-image').eq(index).show();
  $(currentSelection).closest('.img-to-select')
    .prevAll('.custom-carousel__title').find('span')
    .html($(currentSelection).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

```css
.custom-carousel {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-image>img {
  width: 50px;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item>img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.img-to-select {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img-to-select>.img-to-select__item.selected {
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image" style="display: block">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-a">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" data-title="image-a">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" data-title="image-a">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-b">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" data-title="image-b">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" data-title="image-b">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-c">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" data-title="image-c">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" data-title="image-c">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-d">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" data-title="image-d">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" data-title="image-d">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" alt="" data-title="image-a">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" alt="" data-title="image-b">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" alt="" data-title="image-c">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" alt="" data-title="image-d">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image" style="display: block">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-a">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" data-title="image-a">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" data-title="image-a">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-b">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" data-title="image-b">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" data-title="image-b">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-c">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" data-title="image-c">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" data-title="image-c">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <div class="main-image" style="display: none">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" media="(max-width: 576px)" data-title="image-d">
          <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" data-title="image-d">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" data-title="image-d">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/295/200/300.jpg?hmac=b6Ets6Bu47pFHcU4UK7lI6xYkfy48orifVzWeHAe0zM" alt="" data-title="image-a">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI" alt="" data-title="image-b">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/67/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=QQ5thxbuAGWtWAFN4RludrKCymojOtz1l6aIxAWLDSY" alt="" data-title="image-c">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/870/200/300.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=ujRymp644uYVjdKJM7kyLDSsrqNSMVRPnGU99cKl6Vs" alt="" data-title="image-d">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have one more additional question, can I edit this post, or is it better to create a new topic? The question is different from the topic

Comment: If it's closely related, feel free to unaccept and revise. Otherwise start fresh.